# A basic question about calculation under geodesic frame

Tags: riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

I have been recently reading some books related to Ricci flow, and I am confused when it comes to the evolution of Levi-Citita connection. That is: If $(M^n,g)$ Is a closed Riemannian manifold, and we have the Ricci flow equation $\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial t}=-2Ric_{ij}$, then we have the evolution of the Christoffel symbol as follows:
$$
\frac{\partial \Gamma_{ij}^k}{\partial t}=\frac{1}{2}g^{kl}(\nabla_ih_{jl}+\nabla_jh_{il}-\nabla_lh_{ij}),
$$
where $h=\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}$, $\nabla_{i}=\nabla_{\partial_i}$.
To prove this equation, we can calculate in geodesic frame for a fixed $p$ since it is a tensor, that is
$$
\frac{\partial \Gamma_{ij}^k}{\partial t}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial g^{kl}}{\partial t}(\partial_ig_{jl}+\partial_jg_{il}-\partial_lg_{ij})+\frac{1}{2}g^{kl}(\partial_i(\frac{\partial g_{jl}}{\partial t})+\partial_j(\frac{\partial_{il}}{\partial t})-\partial_l(\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial t})).
$$
However, we now calculate in the geodesic frame, we have $\Gamma_{ij}^k(p)=0$, consequently we have
$$\frac{\partial \Gamma_{ij}^k}{\partial t}=\frac{1}{2}g^{kl}(\nabla_ih_{jl}+\nabla_jh_{il}-\nabla_lh_{ij}),
$$
Which finishes the proof. This is the standard proof. My question here is, at p we have $g^{kl}(p)=\delta^{kl}$, then the final formula should be
$$
\frac{\partial \Gamma_{ij}^k}{\partial t}=\frac{1}{2}\delta^{kl}(\nabla_ih_{jl}+\nabla_jh_{il}-\nabla_lh_{ij}),
$$
Where $\delta^{kl}=1$, if k=l, else 0. But this seems wrong. I am not clear why. I have read many books and they seem to ignore $g^{kl}(p)$, for example Bennett Chow and Dan Knopf’s book “The Ricci flow: an introduction.”

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. By a geodesic frame, I assume you mean exponential coordinates. In that case, $g^{kl}(p) = \delta^{kl}$.

Comment: My problem is here: in exponential coordinates, we have $g^{kl}=\delta^{kl} as you see, then we can get the final equation as above. But in standard textbook, we can only have the second to the last formula.

Comment: The two formulae are equivalent in a geodesic frame, but the second-to-last is tensorial, and so holds for more general frames

Comment: But the last formula is also tensorial I think since the derivative of Christoffel  symbol  is tensorial.

Comment: I feel it is related to the fact that the geodesic frame is variant under Ricci flow so we can not have $g_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$ for all time t,  but if so, how about the Christoffel symbol?  but if so,  then the Christoffel symbol is variant for time t hence we get the formula only at some time t, then how to verify the whole formula for all time.

Comment: I am confused is that we can have $\Gamma_{ij}^k(p)=0$, but we cannot have $g_{ij}(p)=\delta^{ij}$ under normal coordinates?

Comment: Neither Christoffel symbols nor their partial derivatives are tensorial.

Comment: You have to be very careful when doing calculations with a metric that varies in time, such as for the Ricci flow. Both $g$ and $\Gamma$ obviously depend on time. But you can also change the coordinates in a time-dependent way. In fact, if you want the coordinates to always be exponential coordinates, as time varies, then you have to modify the coordinates in a time-dependent way.

Comment: In other words, as metric evolves, the exponential map is changing so $g_{ij}$ is not always $\delta^{ij}$ except the initial time $t$? But the christoffel symbol is 0 since it is in the exponential coordinate.

Comment: I am sure that $g_{ij}$ is not always $\delta_{ij}$ under Ricci flow. And, therefore,  $\Gamma_{ij}^k$ is not always zero.  In your last equation, I think the $\delta^{ij}$ shoulde be changed to $g^{ij}$, otherwise, it is not right.    PS:  I just a beginner of Ricci flow, for reference only.

Comment: @lanse7pty thanks a lot. I get your point